# define dynamic route without slash

Tags: next.js

I have a next 12 application. I have a SSR component with a routes such as /product1232312321.

my solution up until now was to create two folders one as product and the other one inside it as [id]. then to redirect from  /product/1232312321 to /product1232312321 from config.js as below:

```
{
        source: '/product /:slug',
        destination: '/product :slug',
        permanent: true,
},
```

this solution is no longer working for me. is there a way to define this route without the slash like this /product1232312321?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not recommending this, but you can make the page file [id].tsx (or js) then using the param passed you could pull in the `id` ("product1111") and render the page that way.

Note that this is very bad practice, and will cause any 404's to be directed to that page, so you'll need to do some param checking to ensure it is in the format of `product{id}`.

I would highly suggest you move to the standard `/product/[id]` practice noted in the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes).